# How to use cd and vi in execl function

Tags: c, linux, shell, command, execl

I want to use the `execl` function to invoke both commands cd and vi from my c program, but it does not work.
This is what I did for rm and ls:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
execl("/bin/rm", "rm", args[1], NULL); //args is the array containing the arguments of the command
```

It works for `ls` and `rm`, but when I try to do the same thing with `vi` and `cd` it does not work.

Comment: There was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370470/execvp-in-c-not-going-through-ar) question like 10 minutes ago. And for some reason your `cd` and `vi` do not match the code with `ls` and `rm`.

Comment: If you try to exec `cd` it won't work, partly because `cd` is a builtin to the shell, not a standalone program you can exec, and also because, if you change directory in a subprocess, it doesn't affect the parent (which is precisely why it has to be a builtin to the shell).  `vi`, on the other hand, should have worked, unless maybe if there were problems getting its hand on the terminal -- since of course it's a highly interactive program.

Comment: What is the failure mode when you try to exec `vi`?  Can you show us the exact code you used for that?

Comment: Since you don't show the code that failed, it's hard to know what went wrong.  On a Mac, there _is_ a command `/usr/bin/cd`, but it is of very, very limited use — the command changes directory, but doesn't affect the invoking program.  (If I run `/usr/bin/cd /some/where/non-existent`, it gives an error message `/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: /some/where/non-existent: No such file or directory`.  So, it could be used to check whether the target directory exists and is accessible, but that's about it.  And yes, it is a shell script.)

Comment: Note that if you are writing a shell, you will not be using `execl()` very often.  You will need to use `execv()`, `execvp()`, `execve()` or `execvpe()` depending on context and what's available.

Comment: As in the question I linked in the first comment: You *can't* use `exec*` functions one after the other as they just don't return in the good case.

Comment: Better to use `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char*)NULL);` for rare platforms that do not make `NULL` same size/encoding as a `char*`.   OTOH, such machine may not have `execl()`.