# Ellipsis NULL, nullptr and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, null, variadic-functions, nullptr

I have function taking a variable and NULL terminated list of pointer arguments using the elipsis. I know about variable length template argument lists. It is about legacy code. Will the following two calls lead to undefined behaviour because the terminator is interpreted as Serializable* by va_arg? What are the differences between the two calls?

```
void serialize(Serializable* first, ...) {
    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, first);

    while(1)
    {
        Serializable* arg = va_arg(vl, Serializable*);

        if(arg == NULL)
            break;

        /* serialize arg here */
    }
}

serialize(obj1, obj2, obj3, NULL);
serialize(obj1, obj2, obj3, nullptr);
```

Comment: Is it possible to corret the Typo in the title?

Comment: Yes, just [edit] your post.

Comment: Why not use variadic templates instead of this very bad C-style code?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher *"I know about variable length template argument lists. It is about legacy code."* - OP

Comment: Even if it's legacy code, you can still change it to use better typed code. Except if you are stuck with an old compiler.

Comment: It is not real legacy code. It is for a presentation. I want to find out, if there are any risks switching to from NULL to nullptr for existing code.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher No. Changing code in such a fundamental way has a cost. You don't just rewrite a legacy application for the sake of being "more modern". Or, if you do, I fire you ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, it depends, I don't write such things for the sake of being modern. I would write tests first, but if you would not consider changing the code while having tests, then I would probably fire you.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher It's called "legacy" for a reason. Unless you are making the application non-legacy (which is a whole other discussion), changing the structure of such an old application purely for style reasons is frankly misconductful. Sure, you have tests, but you can't guarantee not introducing bugs, and _what is the benefit against this risk?_ I understand that the new code may be more easy to maintain etc, but then those are valid reasons to _de-legacy_ the code and so again we're back to the discussion not being about changing a legacy app _per se_.

Comment: Obviously OP was tasked with some refactorings which can be defined as stylish, so obviously this change can also be on the table.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Sorry, where was that mentioned? I must have missed a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

Quoting [cppreference.com on `va_arg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg):

> If the type of the next argument in `ap` (after promotions) is not compatible with `T`, the behavior is undefined, unless:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types; or
> - one type is pointer to `void` and the other is a pointer to a character type (`char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`).

(This very closely matches the actual C11 wording; remember, `va_arg` is defined by C, not C++.)

Now, C11's definition of "compatible types" is summed up by [another cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Compatible_types), which teaches us that for your `NULL` to have a type compatible with `Serializable*`, the pointee-type of `NULL` would have to be compatible with `Serializable`.

Now, [`NULL` has an implementation-defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21559462/560648) so you can't know what it is, but it's certainly not going to be one that's compatible with `Serializable`, unless that is simply a type alias for `void` or `int` and you get lucky.

With the `nullptr` [you get `void*`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#9), but then again see above.

Comment: It's about "compatibility" in the C sense, me thinks. And if [I read correctly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type), `void*` (which is [what `nullptr_t` is converted to](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#9) when passed as an extra ellipsis argument) is not compatible with `Serializable*`.

Comment: Aren't promotions implicit conversions?

Comment: We can make an analogy with `printf("%p", x)`. GCC allows `x` to be `void *` or `nullptr_t`, but issues a warning for any other pointer type and `NULL`. But I agree that the warning could be broken...

Comment: @StoryTeller Agreed. Was researching :) (a bit late :P)

Comment: @MartinFehrs Promotions are a limited subset of all implicit conversions. That is, you can classify them as implicit conversions, but that doesn't mean "promotion" entails _any possible implicit conversion_. Promotions are basically just arsing about making `int`s bigger

Comment: So both versions lead to undefined behaviour? Is this a real world problem? I've seen code written like this.

Comment: @MartinFehrs Looks like it! People abuse `NULL` all the time tbf